# API for NVMe driver

Tags: api, nvme

I am new to storage servers.
Is there any API available to communicate with NVMe driver?
Recently i came across IOCTl and SPDK, but i didn't get a clear idea about how to use the same.
Does NVMe passthru command come under IOCTL?

[tried to do nvme read as seen in an example, read a file using nvme read in two ways using nvme utility and io passthru. Using nvme utility read success msg is obtained, while io pasthru command didnt return a read success msg.do io passthru command return a success msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVjsF.jpg)

Comment: What is it that you're trying to accomplish?  Why do you want to communicate with the NVMe driver?

Comment: i want to read data from an NVMe SSD in a SSD storage server, can i do this, simply using nvme read command. as i am new to this storage servers , i am not familiar with read and write an ssd

Comment: Why is it that you need to have specific knowledge of the technology providing storage to the server?  One normally maps a SSD onto a portion of the host's filesystem, and then reads and writes to/from it via standard filesystem calls.  Application code normally doesn't and shouldn't have knowledge of the underlying hardware.  If you're talking about storage on a remote server, this is even more true.  In those cases, you would normally be using `ftp`, `sftp`, `NFS`, or some other network protocol.  Why can't you read and write using standard filesystem or network I/O operations?

Comment: i am not familiar with the mentioned filesystem calls